# Material Design - 5 items in a section. Because 12 modulo 5 equals ugly

Tags: css, material-design

I am using the Material Design Light library on a page where I have 5 items which I would like to take up equal parts of a section:

```
<section class="section--center mdl-grid mdl-grid--no-spacing mdl-shadow--2dp social-section">
  <a href="http://twitter.com" target="_blank" class="mdl-cell--2-col mdl-cell--2-col-phone mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-color-text--primary-contrast frontpage-social-button gt-info-twitter">
    <i class="fa fa-twitter big-icon"></i>
  </a>
  <a href="http://facebook.com" target="_blank" class="mdl-cell--2-col mdl-cell--2-col-phone mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-color-text--primary-contrast frontpage-social-button gt-info-facebook">
    <i class="fa fa-facebook big-icon"></i>
  </a>
  <a href="http://linkedin.com" target="_blank" class="mdl-cell--2-col mdl-cell--2-col-phone mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-color-text--primary-contrast frontpage-social-button gt-info-linkedin">
    <i class="fa fa-linkedin big-icon"></i>
  </a>
  <a href="http://youtube.com" target="_blank" class="mdl-cell--2-col mdl-cell--2-col-phone mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-color-text--primary-contrast frontpage-social-button gt-info-youtube">
    <i class="fa fa-youtube big-icon"></i>
  </a>
  <a href="http://plus.google.com" target="_blank" class="mdl-cell--2-col mdl-cell--2-col-phone mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-color-text--primary-contrast frontpage-social-button gt-info-gplus">
    <i class="fa fa-google-plus big-icon"></i>
  </a>
</section>
```

And I want them to fill up the whole section, not just use `mdl-cell--1-offset` on the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unable to find a native MDL way to do this, I added the following to my `frontpage-social-button` class:

```
width:20%;
```